# $F_1F_2$ Normal extension of k

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, normal-extension

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be finite normal extensions of $k$ contained in the field $E$. Prove that their composite $F_1F_2$ (the smallest subfield of $E$ containing both $F_1$ and $F_2$) is also a normal extension of $k$.

I am fairly new to Field theory and I am having trouble trying to solve the question.

Comment: Well, we need to start somewhere. What does "normal" mean? How should the proof begin?

Comment: Since both are normal extensions of $k$ then $F_1$ and $F_2$ are minimal splitting field of some polynomial over $k$. But I do not understand how to use this information to prove the result.

Comment: So, let $f_1 \in k[x]$ be a polynomial for which $F_1$ is the splitting field. Then $F_1 = k(r_1, \dots, r_n)$ where $r_1, \dots, r_n$ are the roots of $f_1$. Likewise, we get $f_2 \in k[x]$ with roots $s_1, \dots, s_m$ such that $F_2 = k(s_1, \dots, s_m)$. Now $F_1 F_2$ is just $k(r_1, \dots, r_n, s_1, \dots, s_m)$... what polynomial should that be the splitting field of?

Comment: The polynomial will be $f_1f_2$? Also how is $F_1F_2$ = $k(r_1,...r_n,s_1,...s_m)$?

Comment: Yes! Now just turn that into a rigorous proof :) Hopefully you can see that there was no magic involved here -- I literally just expanded the definition of "normal extension" and used that to describe the composite extension, and you figured out the rest. This is always how you should approach proofs -- even if you don't see the full picture immediately, at least begin by expanding the relevant definitions and writing down precisely what it is you need to do/show.

Comment: Well, by definition, we need to show that $k(r_1,\dots,r_n,s_1,\dots,s_m)$ is the smallest field containing both $F_1$ and $F_2$. It certainly contains both $F_1$ and $F_2$, so all we have left to do is show that $k(r_1,\dots,r_n,s_1,\dots,s_m)$ is contained in any field extension of $k$ which contains both $F_1$ and $F_2$...

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so much for your help!